# Want disable click on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I scroll on my div which have some buttons. Button's are auto clicked when i scroll on my div. How can i stop auto clicking during scroll. The code is here

```
$(document).ready(  
function() {   
$("#scroller1").niceScroll({ 
    cursorwidth:"10px",  
    cursorborder: "10px",  
    bouncescroll: false,  
    horizrailenabled: false,  
    touchbehavior:true,  
    grabcursorenabled: true,  
    autohidemode:false,  
    preventmultitouchscrolling: false,    
   });  
});
```

jsfiddle link  check 20 to 30 seconds
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWwOMw

Comment: can you set a jsfiddle with full code?

Comment: how can they get clicked automatically on scroll ? Do you have any hover functions which are getting executed ?

Comment: Hey try reducing the width of button and li elements

Comment: Please decipher "auto clicked" term.